# Update component according to redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to create an app with react and `redux`. My component subscribed to several states from the `redux` store, some of the state-data need to be prepared before the rendering can take place. Do I need to put the `prepareData` function into `componentWillReceiveProps` and write it to the state afterwards? It seems to create a lot of queries in the `componentWillReceiveProps`. Is there a best practice?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if (this.props.dataUser !== nextProps.dataUser) {
        this.prepareData(nextProps.dataUser);
    }

    if (this.props.dataProject !== nextProps.dataProject) {
        .....
    }

    if (this.props.dataTasks !== nextProps.dataTasks) {
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use the props and avoid state completely in your component? If you have computation, maybe do them in your mapStateToProps method

Comment: @Axnyff it is an array with objects and properties, that's why I need to prepare the data.

Comment: This looks like 3 different states in my opinion, why not have 3 different components and render those three inside your component that you are describing here? And really, no need to have a local state, as your redux store will contain all the data

Comment: Depends on what you are doing inside `this.prepareData()`. Are you updating local states inside it?

Comment: @Jaye I cannot use the data directly from the props, I prepare the data and write them to the state

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` seems to be the best place to handle that then. Process is called syncing props to local state: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Answer (score 0):

As Axnyff suggests, you can do your data preparation in `mapStateToProps`, this will trigger a render each time your redux state updates (your component can be stateless this way) :

```
mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const dataUserPrepared = prepareData(state.dataUser);
    return { dataUser: dataUserPrepared };
}
```

If you have a lot of different data to prepare, which updates individually, that can be a loss in performance.

In this case you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` like in your question, this is fine because the `setState` in your `prepareData()` function will be batched with the received props to trigger only one render per prop update.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using an app without `redux` then the solution would be to prepare your data before you call `this.setState()`.

I believe the same solution applies to when using `redux`, your can prepare your data inside your `action` because you return the action object having a `type and payload`. 
You can also prepare your data inside your `reducer` before returning the state object. 
You could even prepare your data inside `mapStateToProps` of your component.

But in case you want to specific conditions under which component should re-render when state changes, then you do that in `shouldComponentUpdate()`